# intellij is importing wrong gradle version on my machine after I changed it

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

Via gradle/wrapper/gradle.properties, I changed the gradle version in this project

github.com/deanhiller/webpieces

I re-import into intellij but it is still on gradle 5.3.1.  I am trying to use an api in gradle 5.5.1 but intellij keeps having me depend on 5.3.1 when I explore the jars being used.

or perhaps there is a better way then using this dependency for gradle plugins

```
 compile gradleApi()
```

since it is completely bringing in the wrong jar file for gradle(5.3.1 instead of 5.5.1).
thanks,
Dean

Comment: Which Gradle version [is configured](https://i.imgur.com/hM9Suev.png) in IntelliJ IDEA? What IDE version do you use? Does it help if you delete .idea directory and reimport the project from `build.gradle`?

Comment: Also remember to refresh the Gradle project in IntelliJ after upgrading (when you use `gradleApi()`)